# Synchronization between a method and a set of methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have an object called FooBar which exposes N number of Foo methods and a close method. Foo methods fetches some data and Close disposes the object(which essentially aborts all the Foo methods if they are running). Foo methods can run in parallel(multi-threaded support).

I want Close to work only after all the Foo methods are done. For this, I've added a lock object in all the Foo and Close methods. This way I ensure Close doesn't succeed if Foo operation is going on.

With the above synchronization design, I lose the ability to run Foo methods in parallel.

Is there any design pattern/way to solve the above problem?

Comment: are you wiling to use TPL?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a lock object, just use a standard integer member to denote how many Foo methods are running.

Increment this when a Foo method starts and decrement it when it ends.

Close can then check this is zero before continuing.

Comment: I had thought about this approach but the integer needs to be protected with a lock too since a single Foo method can be called from many threads simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, so knowing this, how about a different lock for each Foo method too?

Comment: There can be 100s of such methods.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to protect each Foo with a lock?  If you can run multiple different Foos at the same time, are you sure you cannot run a single Foo many times in parallel on separate threads?

Comment: Yes, as I have mentioned earlier, Foo methods are protected with a lock to ensure Close doesn't dispose. Just to synchronize with Close. I don't see single method being run in parallel on separate threads as they fetch the same data on the same object. There's no use case for this behavior.

Comment: Yes, but you say "Foo methods can run in parallel(multi-threaded support)."  If this can happen, then why worry about someone calling the same Foo on more than one thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TPL waitall to execute all the tasks before running close method. I have cut pasted some code from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(action, i);
    }
```

Code above lines up all the tasks so you very well replace them with your method calls inside Facotry.StartNew(yourmethodcall, i)

Once you have created all the tasks then you can call wait all to complete the execution of the tasks. Once wait all is called it program will wait for all the task execution to be completed.

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

After this line of code you can call close method to do rest of the operation.

Comment: Execution of all the Foo methods is not under our control. It is part of an API, which can be executed any point of time.

Comment: No, Code is part of the API.

Comment: Then whats stopping you from creating a new api method which runs all the methods inside foobar in asynchronous fashion like I suggested above?

Comment: They are different methods but all fetch some different kind of data.